# How to compile some dependencies with release

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'd like to build my rust app with "dev" profile, but some of the dependencies with "release" profile (because otherwise they are really slow). How can I selectively specify profiles for my crate dependencies?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cargo is able to override profile for a specific package.

From the  [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#overrides) :

> Profile settings can be overridden for specific packages and
>   build-time crates. To override the settings for a specific package,
>   use the package table to change the settings for the named package:
>
> ```
> # The `foo` package will use the -Copt-level=3 flag.
> [profile.dev.package.foo]
> opt-level = 3
> ```

While compiling with `dev` profile, this will override optimize level for `foo` package.

---

- If you want to optimize few dependency with a default value from `dev` profile and more from a `release` profile:

```
#override target package to build with dev default(opt-level) 
[profile.dev.package.bar]
opt-level = 0 

#override all other dependencies to build with release default(opt-level) 
[profile.dev.package."*"]
opt-level = 3
```

---

- If you want to optimize all of your dependencies except your
  application(*also workspace members*)

```
[profile.dev.package."*"]
opt-level = 3
```

---

**See also :**

- [Default Profiles with their default settings](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#default-profiles)
- [Reference of Profile Settings](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/profiles.html#profile-settings)