# Is there a crate that can read insanely large png files quickly with no data loss. (17mb files with 21600 x 10800)

Tags: rust, large-files, image-loading, topography, large-image

My rust app needs to have access to world heightmap data (topography) which I have downloaded from nasa's official website. Currently, with me using the Image crate https://lib.rs/crates/image, it takes roughly 1 minute for the entire app to load, which is completely unacceptable. Is there any rust crate that is specifically designed to load images that large? I do not want to compress the file aswell, as that might possible mess up the height data.

Comment: Compile in release mode (aka `cargo build/run --release`). I have an 83MB .png locally that loads in about a minute in debug mode with the `image` crate but within a *second* in release mode.

Comment: Thanks, I don't have any idea why, but it loaded in about a second when I run it in release mode. It will make it hard for me to debug unfortunately, but I see I don't have much of a choice.

Comment: Perhaps you can specify `opt-level=3` only for the `image` crate.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60751806/how-to-compile-some-dependencies-with-release

Comment: Oh thanks, I forgot about that feature in rust. I have used bevy before so I should have thought of that.

Comment: *"I do not want to compress"* I hope you are talking about lossy compression, because there are good lossless compression formats, like png.

Answer (score -1):

I ran the application in release mode and everything works fine now.